# When do you use a String over int

Tags: java, string

Hey I'm first year university learning the basics of Java. I was looking through a program that measures the average Rainfall within a year using Arrays. Within the constructor it uses `String year;`  -- why would you use `String` and not `int`? 
What exactly are `Strings` and what are they used for -- in simplicity**

I tried looking on the internet but there's such a huge variation and it's too complex for me to understand. I have only been learning about Java / CS for a couple months now in University.

Comment: It really depends how it's using the information. You _could_ use either data type. Perhaps post the program here?

Comment: The best place to learn is : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Comment: Please refer "Datatypes in Java"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conventionally, you use the type that best fits your scenario.

- If you need to do math associated with a number, use a datatype capable of that, like `int`, `double`, `long`, `float`, etc.
- If you don't need to perform math on it, or you're using it as a label, then a `String` is acceptable.

(In all actuality, if you really wanted to do something with the date, such as subtract two years together, ideally you'd use an appropriate object for *that*, as well.)

From what you describe, the years are only really meant as a column header, and nothing more is required of them, so a `String` is the only appropriate type to use.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the information is coming from and where it is going.

For example, I was recently doing a project that involved an xml serialization tool where the serializer needed to convert both strings and ints.  It was easier to use the serializer if I just stored all of the variables in java as strings. I didn't need to do any computation with the ones that were numbers anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is used with a collection of characters like for example:

- **Strings:** Earth, School, Window
- **Ints:** From -2147483648  to 2147483647 (Without decimals)
- **Chars:** a, b, c, d, e

We can classify like this:

- **For numbers:** byte, short, int, float, double, long
- **For characers:** String, char
- **For Booleans (True/False):** Boolean

For more information, you can check it from the [Oracle Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

A String is text, Integer a number.
The reason you use both of these is the way they work.

For example the summing

```
String string1 = "1";
String string2 = "2";
System.out.printLn(string1 + string2);
// Will output 12

int x = 1;
int y = 2;
System.out.printLn(x + y);
// This will output 3
```

Comparing is also different for the two.

Comment: *"Comparing is also different for the two."* Not when you're using  `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: Ah, will change that. I assumed an "Integer" was the same as "int" in c#, my bad.

Comment: Thanks it makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

better answer:
Strings are used to store purely text based data. This can include: words, individual characters, individual numbers and symbols, or any combination of any of these things. To define a String, you would type:

```
    String variable = "some words and numbers here 12345?!";
```

anything inside the quotation marks will be part of variable.

Integers are used to store non decimal numbers. For instance, if you wanted to store numerical data that can be utilized by math operations (such as +,-,/,*) then you need to use an integer. While strings can hold numerical data, they can not directly be used in math operations.
Example:

```
    //this works
    int a=4;
    int b=2;
    int c=(a+b);
    //int c now equals 6
    //this does not work
    String a="4";
    String b="2";
    String c=(a+b);
    //String c now equals 42, because you are adding the strings "4"+"2", not the numbers 4+2.
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A String is used when you want to store character data and an int would be used when you want to store numerical data that is between -2147483648 and 2147483648. A Sting can hold a very large number of characters, but each character will take 2 bytes or 16 bits of memory to store. An int is a fixed size of 4 bytes or 32 bits. So storing a year like "2016" takes more memory to store when stores as a String then it does to store as an integer.

A reason someone may store a year in a String as opposed to an int might be because they would like to perform common String operations on it. As a string it is easy to read code that uses only the last two digits for instance.

```
String year = "2016";
System.out.println("Today is Thursday 02/04/" + year.substring(2));
```

This might be easier to read than performing some arithmetic on an int to get the same result.

```
int year = 2016;
int shortYear = year - 2000;
System.out.println("Today is Thursday 02/04/" + shortYear;
```

There are many more reasons but this is a simple example.